# ios non-renewing subscription's duration in sandbox

Tags: ios, sandbox, subscription, duration

We have "5 min" sandbox duration for "1 month" auto-renewing subscription.
What is the duration of the sandbox subscription, if we're working with "1 month" NON-renewing subscription?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess its upto you.
Let me explain - As storekit wont keep any data nor will it inform you about a particular subscription, its duration or how much time it has left etc, in case of Non-renewable subscription, you have to do all the heavy lifting code and check for your content. And you should also mention the duration in itunes about the purchase, and you yourself have to abide by that duration.

During sandbox you can trim down the duration calculation in your application by a large margin factor, then during production you can change it to that it should be.

Comment: You have to do the calculation yourself - 
eg - you can put 1 month calculation as per receipt as 1 minute in your application logic

Comment: Sorry for the previous post. But my problem is here:
1. I purchase the non-renewing subscription
2. I wait 10 minutes (ex, due to my large margin factor for test environment) for expiring. So my project logic thinks that subscription is finished.
3. I want to purchase this subscription again. And I expect the same systems popups (step 1). But I see information that I already have this subscription and I can renew or extend it. So, store's logic thinks that my subscription is still active.